# Mysql ful outer join

Tags: mysql

I have a table named 'emails':

```
     email          domain         timestamp
abcd@google.com    google.com      2019/12/08
abd@google.com     google.com      2019/12/08
abcd@google.com    google.com      2019/12/09
abd@google.com     google.com      2019/12/09
123@google.com     google.com      2019/12/09
```

i want output only for the email that is new compare to previous date, something like this:

```
       email        domain      timestamp
123@google.com     google.com   2019/12/09
```

since mysql don't have full outer join I am using following query but it does not work:

```
 select * from email e1
 left join emails e2
 on e1.domain_searched = e2.domain_searched 
 where
 e1.timestamp = '2019/12/08'

 union

 select * from email e1
 right join emails e2
 on e1.domain_searched = e2.domain_searched 
 where
 e1.timestamp = '2019/12/09';
```

Guys I need your suggestions...thank you in advance...

Comment: Do you mean that you need only e-mails that do not have timestamp prior to some date?  If this is the case then `NOT EXISTS` with a correlated sub-query is quite sufficient. Or, alternatively `GROUP BY` with `HAVING MIN(timestamp) >= <somedate/time>`).

Comment: Your data set in not adequately representative of the problem. See [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) - and asking punters to spot the difference between 'abcd' and 'abd' is a bit cruel in my opinion

Comment: @PM77-1 yes i am looking for only emails that do not have timestamp prior in my db or in other way, it was not in my db at all before...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> i am looking for only emails that do not have timestamp prior in my db
>   or in other way, it was not in my db at all before

With `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select * from emails e
where e.timestamp = '2019/12/09'
and not exists (
  select 1 from emails
  where email = e.email and timestamp < e.timestamp
);
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gLSRDyBTYoyN4o2RF4PCA1/1).
Results:

```
| email          | domain     | timestamp  |
| -------------- | ---------- | -----------|
| 123@google.com | google.com | 2019-12-09 |
```

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you're after something like this.

```
SELECT x.* 
  FROM my_table x 
  LEFT 
  JOIN my_table y 
    ON y.email = x.email
   AND y.timestamp = '2019/12/08'
 WHERE x.timestamp = '2019/12/09'
   AND y.email IS NULL;
```

Note that this is NOT a FULL OUTER JOIN

Comment: It works just fine: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/c9Ac1mk66HbZqYetwEzkLH/0